# Equivalent of the "render twig" (in SF2) in Node Js / Express JS?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have just a little question: is it possible with NodeJS / ExpressJS to call a controller action in views ?

In fact, I search the equivalent of the render Twig of Symfony 2 (i.e. "{{ render(controller('AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentArticles')) }}") in Node JS.

Have you got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

`res.render('viewpath', params)` can take any kind of data including functions and this can be accessed in the view.

```
// CONTROLLER
app.get('/my-route', function (req, res, next) {
    var myFunc = function () {
        // Do something
        return "hello world";
    };

    res.render('my-view', { "myFunc": myFunc });
});

// VIEW
p #{myFunc()}
```

Alternatively, you can add the function as a property in `res.locals`.

```
res.locals.myFunc = function () {
    ...
};
```

This can be accessed in the view using the same way.